# 'Source not found’ when I debug in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I don't want to show the 'Source not found’ error message when I step into a class if the source code is not present in eclipse.

How Can I configure that in Eclipse ?

Comment: @2rs2ts it seems like Rajeev knows that the source will not be found but just wants to skip the part where Eclipse jumps to the aforementioned screen. If this is the case I don't think it's a duplicate question (at least not of the one you linked)

Comment: What would you expect Eclipse to do if you step into a class that has no source code available? It has to show *something*.

Comment: +1 In order to "fix" this you need to link the source code.

Comment: Use [Java Source Attacher](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-source-attacher) Eclipse plugin.